# will redis delete my old express.js sessions?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

i'm using redis as my session store for a node.js + express app...will it automatically delete old sessions after they expire?

...or do I need to do some cleanup on the server side? (so the db doesn't grow too large)

```
  var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express)

  app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      host: cfg.redis.host,
      db: cfg.redis.db
    }), 
    secret: 'foobar'
  }));
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `connect-redis` will make Redis clean out your sessions when they expire.

If I remember correctly, the default session timeout is 24 hours which to me is quite a long time to keep something idle in memory, but you can give it a `ttl` parameter to configure (in seconds) how long you want the sessions kept before Redis expires them.

If you want to make sure for yourself that Redis cleans things up for you, just set the timeout to 30 seconds and have a look in Redis for yourself after the timeout has expired;

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: cfg.redis.host,
    db: cfg.redis.db,
    ttl: 30
  }), 
  secret: 'foobar'
}));
```

The `ttl` options is mentioned [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) and there is some minor extra detail on how it interacts with other options [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/pull/45).

Comment: i set my cookie to expire after 2 weeks, do I need to change ttl to 2 weeks too so they don't get deleted out of redis?

Comment: @chovy Yes, if you really want Redis to keep the sessions in memory for 2 weeks, you'll need to do that. You may want to look into some kind of hybrid session storage though, keeping sessions in Redis that have been active for the last couple of hours and storing them on disk for sessions idle longer than that may be a good idea to save some memory.

Comment: In the 2nd link, what does author mean by "Added ttl option, which comes prior to cookie maxAge. Now session ttl is (options.ttl, cookie.maxAge, oneDay) whichever defined first." -- does that mean it will set ttl to whatever I set cookie.maxAge too?

Comment: @chovy I can't verify this since I don't have things set up on this machine, but it would seem that he is saying that if you don't set `ttl`, it will use `cookie.MaxAge` as a session key TTL. It should be fairly easy to locate the session in Redis and verify, I've never tuned TTL up, just down, so can't speak from experience.

Comment: Pretty sure 24 hours is not the default.  I've not set a ttl, and I'm seeing very old keys in redis.

Comment: Ah, just checked source - default is sess.cookie.maxAge if set, otherwise 24 hours.

Answer (score 6):

It's working as expected. If I do a browser-only session (expires cookie when user-agent closes) then it lives in redis for 24 hours (I did not set a ttl option in connect-redis).

If I set a cookie to expire in 2 weeks, it lives in redis for 14 days.

You can check with these commands:

```
start redis-cli
> keys *
> ttl <key>
```